# OSX Security Unlock Issue using Bamboo

Tags: macos, build-automation, bamboo, osx-server

We are using `Atlassian Bamboo` to build iPhone apps.
We run bamboo remote agent on an OSX Server to build.

The script used [here](http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-automate-your-iphone-app-builds-with-hudson) was modified to fit our needs.

The problem is that for some time the build will be successful then after awhile, we will receive a failed build.
This error message will be displayed.

```
security: SecKeychainOpen /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain: CSSM_ERRCODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

The temporary fix to this is to restart the bamboo agents `(.jar)` then it will work for a while then we will receive this error again.

How do we resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem did you manage to resolve it?